# How to copy a freshly created array containing files to another folder on the same computer

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am new to Powershell but have had experience with various programming languages including dBase III, basic, Fortran (shows my age). I am a musician and launch MP3 files as an accompanyment when I perform live, somewhat like karaoke. I have about 45 different MP3s that I use. I like to change the sequence of the songs that I perform, from time to time and this requires renaming the MP3 file names with a preceeding sequence number. The file names take on the form: "01 songnameA.mp3", "02 songnameB.mp3", "03 songnameC.mp3", etc. I also repeat songs so there might be an "09 songnameA.mp3" in the folder that I play back from. To do this, I typically create a text file that lists the songs in the order that I want to perform them. Each line in the text file has the form "01 Songname X" but no MP3 extension. I then manually copy the mp3 files into a folder and then edit the  names applying a sequence number according to the text file. This is time-consuming.

I have created a Powershell script (version 2) that creates an array of the text file content and an array of the unnumbered MP3 song files. The script creates a 3rd array containing numbered MP3 filenames according to the sequence in the text file. This array does work and I can easily display the list of items in it which have the form "01 SongnameX.mp3". However, I have been unable to copy this array of MP3 filenames with a preceeding sequence number into another folder. I don't know how many variations of the "Copy-Item" statements I have tried but nothing works. The name of the array that contains the filenames is $nsfarray (new song file array). The command I am presently using:

> $nsfarray | copy-item -Destination C:\temp

Returns the following error message:

> Copy-item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\My HP\Documents\My Scripts\01 A Good Time.mp3' because it does not exist.

The path is the default path that I use to run Powershell but somehow the MP3 file names get appended to it. The "01 A Good Time.mp3" is the first item in the `$nsfarray`. I know I am missing something here. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to at least break the large blocks of text into readable paragraphs? There seems to also be a lot of non-relevant information in your post, and removing some of that would help clarify the question. As it stands now, it hurts my eyes and I'm really not clear what you're asking. :-) Thanks.

Comment: The issue I see here is that you have a list of file name that do not exist as well as paths that are not correct. You need to take the "set" list and breakout the real file name so that you can copy it yes?

Answer (score 0):

This is really crude but the issue I see with your input file is that it obviously does not exactly match the real file name that you are looking to copy. So with that in mind lets try this on for size.

```
$musicPath = "c:\music"
$destinationPath = "c:\songset"

$nsfarray = "01 Age of Aquarius"
$nsfarray | ForEach-Object{
    If($_ -match '^\d+ *(?<BaseName>.*)'){
        Copy-Item "$musicPath\$($Matches.BaseName).mp3" -Destination "$_.mp3"
    }
}
```

Work with explicit paths: `$musicPath` and `$destinationPath` so that we do not have to rely on our current location in PowerShell. Then we navigate each value in the array, which I have populated with one example. Now we need to extract the real file name away from your set list number. Using regex we return the part of the string that is not the beginning numbers and spaces and take everything after that.

After we simply copy the file that exists in the `$musicPath` folder that has the name "Age of Aquarius.mp3", which should be the real file, and copy it to the `$destinationPath` as "01 Age of Aquarius.mp3", which is how you want the file for your gig.

**Clarification**

After answering this and looking back at the question I think there is a chance I didn't understand it right. Please update the question if this is not the right way to address this. The core of your problem, if nothing else, is that you are not specifying a proper file path for the mp3s. You need to use the proper source folder and append the mp3 to the string.